# OPC dll - How to retrieve tags value in bulk

Tags: c#, .net, opc, siemens, opc-da

I'm using **OPCSiemensDAAutomation** dll with C# .NET to retrieve tag's value from OPC Server. I managed to retrieve the values using **QueryAvailableProperties()** and **GetItemProperties()**, but the objective is to retrieve 500k tags value per request.

I have tested with 100 tags and the code finished it in 45 seconds, with multi threading resulted in a small improvement of 30 seconds for 100 tags. It'll requires more than 4 hours to achieve the targeted tags volume with current speed. Is there any way that I can retrieve the tags value in bulk with better performance? Thanks.

```
var opcServer = new OPCSiemensDAAutomation.OPCServer();
opcServer.Connect("PCS7.OPCDAServer.1");
ConcurrentBag<DataRow> myBag = new ConcurrentBag<DataRow>(dt.AsEnumerable().ToList());
Parallel.ForEach(myBag, data =>
{
    if (count <= num)
    {
        int cnt;
        Array propertyIds, descriptions, dataTypes, errors, vals;
        try
        {
            opcServer.QueryAvailableProperties(data[0].ToString(), out cnt, out propertyIds, out descriptions, out dataTypes);
            opcServer.GetItemProperties(data[0].ToString(), cnt, propertyIds, out vals, out errors);
            Tags tag = new Tags();
            tag.Id = data[0].ToString();
            tag.Value = vals.GetValue(2).ToString();
            tags.Add(tag);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
});
```

Comment: Getting properties is not designed to be fast in OPC DA. It would be very unusual that you actually needed all properties of thousands of items. For what? OPC DA is designed to be fast with the actual item value/qualities/timestamps, for which you should *not* use properties. Rather, you subscriptions, or, if they are not suitable, one time Reads.

Comment: @ZbynekZ thanks for your suggestion, I have now coded using SyncRead but I am facing this "1073479672- OpcInvalidItemID: The item ID doesn't conform to the server's syntax." error returned when I add OPC item. I have checked that the tags IDs are the same as shown in OPC Scout or other tools. Can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create OPC Groups:

```
OPCGroup myGroup = myServer.addGroup(groupName, isActive, isSubscribed, updateRate);
```

And then you can add tags to your group:

```
myGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("FullAddress", ClientHandle) //a unique number inside the group
```

The `FullAddress` is composed of the OPCChannel name, the connection name and the complete address, ie: `S7:[MyPLCName]DB1.dbx4`.

When you have the group fully populated, you can read all the variables at once.

```
int itemCount = myGroup.OPCItems.Count;
object qualities = null;
object timeStamps = null;
object errors = null;
int serverHandles[itemCount];
Array values = Array.CreateInstance(TypeOf(object), {itemCount },{1})
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){
   serverHandles[i] = myGroup.OPCItems.Item(i + 1).ServerHandle;
   values.SetValue("", i);
}

myGroup.SyncRead(OPCSiemensDAAutomation.OPCDataSource.OPCDevice, itemCount + 1, ServerHandles, values, errors, qualities, timeStamps);
```

Then you will have four new arrays related to the first one `serverHandles`.

It is wise to check the `qualities` array before using the data from the `values` one.